# #WSO2 - DAS - Error in creating index writer: codec header mismatch: actual header=0 vs expected header=1071082519

Tags: lucene, wso2, wso2-das

I am working on wso2 Das product to store business event. I observer that wso2 service is running but the management console is not accessible. I am getting the below error:-

TID: [-1] [] [2016-03-01 16:59:54,185] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.analytics.dataservice.core.indexing.AnalyticsDataIndexer} -  Error in processing index batch operations: Error in creating index writer: codec header mismatch: actual header=0 vs expected header=1071082519 (resource=BufferedChecksumIndexInput(/_data/index/-1234_policystream/4/_ve.si)) {org.wso2.carbon.analytics.dataservice.core.indexing.AnalyticsDataIndexer}
org.wso2.carbon.analytics.dataservice.commons.exception.AnalyticsIndexException: Error in creating index writer: codec header mismatch: actual header=0 vs expected header=1071082519 (resource=BufferedChecksumIndexInput(/_data/index/-1234_policystream/4/_ve.si))
    at org.wso2.carbon.analytics.dataservice.core.indexing.AnalyticsDataIndexer.createIndexWriter(AnalyticsDataIndexer.java:1495)
    at org.wso2.carbon.analytics.dataservice.core.indexing.AnalyticsDataIndexer.updateIndex(AnalyticsDataIndexer.java:1303)
    at org.wso2.carbon.analytics.dataservice.core.indexing.AnalyticsDataIndexer.processIndexOperations(AnalyticsDataIndexer.java:440)
    at org.wso2.carbon.analytics.dataservice.core.indexing.AnalyticsDataIndexer.processIndexOperations(AnalyticsDataIndexer.java:411)
    at org.wso2.carbon.analytics.dataservice.core.indexing.AnalyticsDataIndexer.access$1500(AnalyticsDataIndexer.java:130)
    at org.wso2.carbon.analytics.dataservice.core.indexing.AnalyticsDataIndexer$IndexWorker.run(AnalyticsDataIndexer.java:2064)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.lucene.index.CorruptIndexException: codec header mismatch: actual header=0 vs expected header=1071082519 (resource=BufferedChecksumIndexInput(/_data/index/-1234_policystream/4/_ve.si))
    at org.apache.lucene.codecs.CodecUtil.checkHeader(CodecUtil.java:197)
    at org.apache.lucene.codecs.CodecUtil.checkIndexHeader(CodecUtil.java:256)
    at org.apache.lucene.codecs.lucene50.Lucene50SegmentInfoFormat.read(Lucene50SegmentInfoFormat.java:86)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentInfos.readCommit(SegmentInfos.java:326)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.(IndexWriter.java:830)
    at org.wso2.carbon.analytics.dataservice.core.indexing.AnalyticsDataIndexer.createIndexWriter(AnalyticsDataIndexer.java:1493)
    ... 8 more
    Suppressed: org.apache.lucene.index.CorruptIndexException: checksum status indeterminate: remaining=-1, please run checkindex for more details (resource=BufferedChecksumIndexInput(/_data/index/-1234_policystream/4/_ve.si))
        at org.apache.lucene.codecs.CodecUtil.checkFooter(CodecUtil.java:371)
        at org.apache.lucene.codecs.lucene50.Lucene50SegmentInfoFormat.read(Lucene50SegmentInfoFormat.java:117)
        ... 11 more

Please suggest.

Comment: Are you using a cluster of DAS?

Comment: I am not using cluster of DAS.

I observer today that wso2 carbon service was running but management console was not working. 

Please provide me detail if I miss any steps.

Comment: Could you please share the wso2carbon.log file which can be found at <DAS_HOME>/repository/logs directory ? Can you provide more details on this issue ?